# Accessing contact photo from content uri

Tags: android

I am trying to access a number of things from a contact returned from a Contacts ACTION_PICK Intent- name, phone number, and photo. There is no problem with retrieving the name and phone number, but when I try to access the photo I am getting a SecurityException every time, saying the GLOBAL_SEARCH permission is required. Here is the logcat...

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 uri content://com.android.contacts/contacts/14/photo from pid=4526, uid=10223 requires android.permission.GLOBAL_SEARCH, or grantUriPermission()
```

I've combed stackoverflow and tried every method I've found, and as a sanity check I'm now using the method recommended by google as follows

```
public InputStream retrieveContactPhoto() {

    Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, Long.valueOf(mContactID));
    Uri photoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri, Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(photoUri,
            new String[] {Contacts.Photo.PHOTO}, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) {
        return null;
    }
    try {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            byte[] data = cursor.getBlob(0);
            if (data != null) {
                return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
            }
        }
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
    return null;

}
```

However, I get the same SecurityException in every case. It is thrown at the contentResolver query line. Apparently there's no way to be granted the GLOBAL_READ permission, so I'm not quite sure how to address the problem.
Also, since I've been able to retrieve the name and phone number with no issue, I can't imagine that there's something wrong with how I'm creating the Intent, but for completeness, here is the startActivityForResult() call

```
Intent contactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Contacts.CONTENT_URI);

startActivityForResult(contactIntent, INTERVIEWEE_FROM_CONTACTS);
```

I've scoured the internet and can't find a single case of someone receiving this SecurityException, all I ever see are apps that need the READ_CONTACTS and WRITE_CONTACTS permissions, so I'm sure that I'm overlooking something obvious, but I'm just totally stumped. I am testing on a Nexus 6p, running Nougat.
Please help!

Comment: you can Handle the runtime permissions read contact

Comment: This is happening to me too, but just on a specific device and Android Version 
Brand: Cetrix
Model: MD-03P
Android: 7.0

Did you find a solution about this? 
Just like you said, I haven't found a similar case like this one on internet.

Answer (score 0):

menifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

    <application android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name="MyActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- @res/layout/main.xml -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <Button android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Select a Contact"
            android:onClick="onClickSelectContact" />

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/img_contact"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:adjustViewBounds="true"
               android:contentDescription="Contacts Image"
                />
</LinearLayout>
```

MyActivity .java

```
 public class MyActivity extends Activity {

        private static final String TAG = MyActivity.class.getSimpleName();
        private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PICK_CONTACTS = 1;
        private Uri uriContact;
        private String contactID;     // contacts unique ID


        /**
         * Called when the activity is first created.
         */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
getPermissionToReadUserContacts(); 
        }
     public void getPermissionToReadUserContacts() {
        // 1) Use the support library version ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(...) to avoid
        // checking the build version since Context.checkSelfPermission(...) is only available
        // in Marshmallow
        // 2) Always check for permission (even if permission has already been granted)
        // since the user can revoke permissions at any time through Settings
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // The permission is NOT already granted.
            // Check if the user has been asked about this permission already and denied
            // it. If so, we want to give more explanation about why the permission is needed.
            if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                    Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {
                // Show our own UI to explain to the user why we need to read the contacts
                // before actually requesting the permission and showing the default UI
            }

            // Fire off an async request to actually get the permission
            // This will show the standard permission request dialog UI
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                    READ_CONTACTS_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);
        }
    }
        public void onClickSelectContact(View btnSelectContact) {

            // using native contacts selection
            // Intent.ACTION_PICK = Pick an item from the data, returning what was selected.
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI), REQUEST_CODE_PICK_CONTACTS);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PICK_CONTACTS && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Response: " + data.toString());
                uriContact = data.getData();

                retrieveContactName();
                retrieveContactNumber();
                retrieveContactPhoto();

            }
        }

        private void retrieveContactPhoto() {

            Bitmap photo = null;

            try {
                InputStream inputStream = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(getContentResolver(),
                        ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, new Long(contactID)));

                if (inputStream != null) {
                    photo = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_contact);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
                }

                assert inputStream != null;
                inputStream.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        private void retrieveContactNumber() {

            String contactNumber = null;

            // getting contacts ID
            Cursor cursorID = getContentResolver().query(uriContact,
                    new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts._ID},
                    null, null, null);

            if (cursorID.moveToFirst()) {

                contactID = cursorID.getString(cursorID.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            }

            cursorID.close();

            Log.d(TAG, "Contact ID: " + contactID);

            // Using the contact ID now we will get contact phone number
            Cursor cursorPhone = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                    new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER},

                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " +
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE + " = " +
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE,

                    new String[]{contactID},
                    null);

            if (cursorPhone.moveToFirst()) {
                contactNumber = cursorPhone.getString(cursorPhone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            }

            cursorPhone.close();

            Log.d(TAG, "Contact Phone Number: " + contactNumber);
        }

        private void retrieveContactName() {

            String contactName = null;

            // querying contact data store
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uriContact, null, null, null, null);

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

                // DISPLAY_NAME = The display name for the contact.
                // HAS_PHONE_NUMBER =   An indicator of whether this contact has at least one phone number.

                contactName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            }

            cursor.close();

            Log.d(TAG, "Contact Name: " + contactName);

        }






    }
```

Comment: What is the "number" argument in retrieveContactPhoto(Context context, String number)?

Comment: phone number that u get in onactvityresult

Comment: Same issue. Permission Denial: requires android.permission.GLOBAL_SEARCH, or grantUriPermission().

Comment: add permission to menifest  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

Comment: Yeah this is from evandrix's github gist. I've tried it. Same issue.

Comment: make a demo app and try it

Comment: problem with permission above 22(lolipop) permission not workred ,for that used the dynamic permission

Comment: call the check permissiin method on oncreate